# C# Open Registry Key when only a prefix portion of the name is known

Tags: c#, windows, registry, registrykey

I am working with these two registry keys.

64 bit Firefox version:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Mozilla Firefox (????)
```

32 bit Firefox version:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Mozilla Firefox xx.xx.xx (x86 en-US)
```

What I want is to read the key called `InstallLocation` inside that path. The issue is in the path. The path has Firefox version which has version number in it.

I can hard code the path, but when Firefox is updated, the the path is also updated, so it won't work after the update.

Is there a way to dynamically just read the part of the path and parse out the version to reach to the key?

In other words, is there a way to read the path up to `Mozilla Fireox` and ignore the rest, because I just want see if it this path exist, if it does, go inside the path to get the key-value.

**Update**

Thanks to konkked

```
var has32bit = 
     Registry.LocalMachine
        .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")
        .GetSubKeyNames()
        .Any(a=>a.StartsWith("Mozilla Firefox"));

var has64bit = 
     Registry.LocalMachine
        .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")
        .GetSubKeyNames()
        .Any(a=>a.StartsWith("Mozilla FireFox"));
```

How can I get a key-value inside the Mozilla Firefox folder?? Because the above code only returning true of false.

Comment: get all of the keys in the ...\Uninstall "folder", then use substring matching to find the firefox one in that list?

Comment: There should be a better way to do this rather than collecting alllll of the keys inside uninstall, as it can grow pretty big. @MarcB thank you tho.

Comment: Just read the correct version from the Uninstall\MozillaMaintenanceService\DisplayVersion value.  Do leave it up to the user to uninstall his favorite programs.

Comment: @Omar, FYI you shouldn't add the answer to your question, it is better to just mark my answer as the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Try using below and it will have the install path

var path = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe", "", null);

Comment: User could have 32bit AND 64bit Firefox installed, so that would only give me one path depending on their machine. Is there a way to read the path up to `Mozilla Fireox` and ignore the rest, because I just want see if it's installed, if it is, and go inside the path to get the key-value.

Answer (score 0):

You could get all of the subkeys of an entry using [RegistryKey.GetSubKeyNames Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getsubkeynames(v=vs.110).aspx) and then do a where to see if any are FireFox

```
var has32bit = 
     Registry.LocalMachine
        .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")
        .GetSubKeyNames()
        .Any(a=>a.StartsWith("Mozilla Firefox"));

var has64bit = 
     Registry.LocalMachine
        .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")
        .GetSubKeyNames()
        .Any(a=>a.StartsWith("Mozilla FireFox"));
```

Also notice in a comment you said

> There should be a better way to do this rather than collecting alllll (sic)
>   of the keys inside uninstall, as it can grow pretty big. @MarcB thank
>   you tho.

I don't think there is a better way to partially match against a subkey

And to answer comment :

> Thank you! it's working. Is there a away (sic) to get values inside that
>   full path afte (sic) like InstallLocation

You can get the actual subkey when you decide which version you want, but I am not sure how you are going to decide that, but here is an example of how to access the values:

```
var subkey32BitBase = 
     Registry.LocalMachine
        .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");

var fireFoxKeys = subkey32BitBase.GetSubKeyNames(subkey32base);

foreach(var fireFoxSubKey in fireFoxSubKeys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
      subkey32BitBase
        .GetSubKey(fireFoxSubKey)
        .GetValue("InstallLocation")
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! it's working. Is there a away to get values inside that full path afte like `InstallLocation`?

Answer (score 0):

If Firefox is installed it will register itself to the "Open With..." list of HTML files.

The application names to open html files with are stored under the file type's registry key, under the OpenWithList subkey. The path to applications themselves are stored under HKCR\Applications.